# Source- code of webpage doesn't change when scrolling the page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webbrowser-control

I need to search Facebook for posts by a keyword. since it's not possible with Facebook-API, i'm trying to do it with WebBrowser object.
It work, but i need to scroll the page to get more results. I'm making the scroll, but the source code of WebBrowser object doesn't change. Any suggestions what can i do to get the updated source code?
I tried using the Explore WebBrowser object and the GeckoFX.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, don´t do that. if it´s not available with the graph api, forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Using ChromeDriver, i made a simple test where i could easily load the pagesource, scroll down and get the new pagesource. The length was 100k higher after a scroll.

```
        using (IWebDriver browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver())
        {
            // Open facebook
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.facebook.com");

            // Scroll down
            var pageSourceLengthBefore = browser.PageSource.Length;
            browser.FindElement(By.TagName("textarea")).SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
            var pageSourceLengthAfter = browser.PageSource.Length;

            // Result
            Console.WriteLine(pageSourceLengthBefore + " / " + pageSourceLengthAfter);
        }
```

Note: focusing an input is required before you sendkeys. Thats why i select the textarea.

Comment: i don't familiar with the OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver. What steps i need to do, so i can test this code?

Comment: The code is in C#. You need to create a unit test solution, and install the chromedriver nuget (search for selenium).